# Как повторить имя папки?

Tags: bash, linux

Я выполняю команду

```
ls /home/user/folder
```

После этого нужно перейти в эту же папку. То есть выполнить

```
cd /home/user/folder
```

Сейчас я кликаю по дважды мышью по пути в предыдущей команда, а затем щелкая колесиком, чтобы скопировать путь. Есть ли удобный способ сделать это без мыши?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае проще всего использовать спец-символ !$.

```
> echo 123456789123456789> echo !$echo 123456789123456789
```

`!$` повторит последний введенный аргумент предыдущей команды.

Answer (score 1):

править строчку все равно придется, рекомендую пользоваться хоткеями Ctrl-A, Ctrl-E и т.п.